# Howto use FB Graph to post a message on a page feed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have created an app, and now i want to post a message on one of my pages wall with use of the new Graph API. Is this do-able?

below is the steps which i do

**Using this to Get access code**

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1498653617947&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/post_on__my_page/index2.html&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access
```

**Than use this to get access token**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1498653617947&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/post_on__my_page/index2.html&client_secret=seceret&code=AQDCqJNJnCvnFKVdbCyTp2vfzbT0ADbNgYsQ_2YtDdC_O2aIOwvkjx52HNcp3uiuBANJqOhb_M2sptB-lRrIECZxi5kZpzljez1J1oOtTp25gTnNDmV-RCVvR97DMiRAprNtwUBcstAotjsyYo5cNwJCWnkcgNigwhbQtE5Jp22sluVcZKhnO43cWQE#_=_
```

**Now get page id and page access token from below**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts/?access_token=the_access_token_above
```

***use this to post on my page ***

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1916117518646/feed?message:testmessage&access_token=aceess_token
```

any one please explain which point is wrong because instead of posting is just show posts  details

i found that some thing wrong in this below code any one please suggest what and how to do

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1916117518646/feed?message:testmessage&access_token=aceess_token
```

Comment: "any one please suggest what and how to do" --- I have given you 2 great links. Have you even checked them?!

Comment: @zerkms yes i read both completely and also read its some related guides e.g., post, message etc 

Thank you so much for your links 
but i still get nothing :( 
sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always highly suggest to people experimenting around for the first time to use the Graph API Explorer tool.  It helps solidify the structure of the Graph and how to access it.  See https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Another thing I always recommend is to lint the access_token you are trying to use.  See https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint.  This is to ensure you have the right token with the correct permissions.

Also the access_token you use to post to a page must be a page token and not a user token.  In your above example, it's unclear as to which one you're using since you've named both the same.  I know you said you're using it, but with that variable name being the same, I always wonder.

Also the you need to do an HTTP Post and not an HTTP get to post a message.  Again, play around in the graph API explorer until you can do it there.  Once you've done it there, it's fairly trivial to do it with one of the SDKs.

Comment: thanks for your reply 
i used page access token 
but i dont known how to use and make HTTP POST :(
and below is the info from Debugger 
'Application ID 
1498636177 : post on my page
User ID 
100001867519270 : Danish Iqbal
Issued 
1326525484 : 11:18 pm Jan 13 2012
Expires 
Never
Valid True
Origin Web
Scopes create_note email manage_pages offline_access photo_upload publish_stream read_stream share_item status_update video_upload'

Comment: Try it in the Graph API Explorer and let us know if you can accomplish it.  Then we'll move on to how to get it accomplished inside of an application.

Comment: i am feeling so bad for still not getting
as i understand we can get only access token form api explorer am i right 
if yes than how can i find that through page access token i can able to post on my page wall

Comment: Exactly the same way you described in your question above. `me/accounts`

Comment: thanks for your answer but actually this answer is not solve my problem and yet no one posted the correct answer but i get the solution 
as i mention in above question i want to known the correct url for posting and i get the correct url to post through url

thanks for your kind favour

Comment: Then could you please post the answer below, wait the required 12 or 24 hours, then accept your answer so the question closes please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform `POST` request, not `GET`, and pass parameters in `POST` body, not in the url

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile

Comment: i will make the complete app ltr but first i want to check is this work 
will you please correct my url to post because thrugh url i just want to check that is working 
i already read your fb linked guide 

Thank you so much for you kind favor

Comment: @Danish Iqbal: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you've said. It is **impossible** to "correct your url" because it is **not possible** to post using `GET`. It is impossible by definition

Comment: @zermk mean you not able to change this link from GET to POST

Comment: @zermk i hope you can able to post on a fb page through link

Comment: @Danish Iqbal: yes, you can, but you need to perform `POST` request, not `GET`

Comment: @zermk but i dont known how to perform post request :(

Comment: @Danish Iqbal: you can start using FB PHP SDK if you can do that from the scratch. There is a complete sample on my second link